# nodemon & nodeclipse wont autorestart on file change

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodeclipse, nodemon

I managed to setup nodeclipse with nodemon and I can now start my server.js script with monitor (nodemon) but something strance occurs:

1. On file change (even on the server.js) nodemon wont restart
2. In nodeclipse console I dont see the normal nodemon output, ex:

> ```
> 1 Aug 15:20:05 - [nodemon] v1.2.1
> 1 Aug 15:20:05 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
> 1 Aug 15:20:05 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
> 1 Aug 15:20:05 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
> ```

PS: I' ve setup monitor path to nodemon.js which is installed with -g parameter
    also I can not create any type of run configuration for "Node with monitor"

Is there any way to autorestart the server in nodeclipse even without nodemon if there isn't any other option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I ended up creating a Node application run configuration and simply added in the arguments tab -> Node arguments the path of `nodemon.js`

In my case : `C:\Users\syd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js`

Now I'm able to get console feed as well stop the node server from eclipse and auto restart on file changes :)

Comment: Which variable?